# use of UISearchController but tableView is not reloaded

Tags: objective-c, ios9, reloaddata, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to add search bar to search through my tableView. There is only one TableViewController in which searchBar is added. I checked all existing guides and apple example codes and followed the instructions but somehow my tableView is not reloaded after entering search string. I checked my codes with NSLog, and I'm sure the the search text is correctly uploaded and  and the new array is filtered using NSPredicate.I have added [self.tableView reloadData] at the end of "updateSearchResultsForSearchController:" method but still my tableViewController is not updated. I am new to iOS programming and not sure what i am doing wrong. Appreciate if you can have a quick glance on my codes and feedback to me. Here is the summary :

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *myList;   //original data list
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *mysearchResult;   //filtered list



  - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.searchController=[[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater=self;
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation=NO;
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate=self;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView=self.searchController.searchBar;
        self.definesPresentationContext=YES;
        [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    }
    -(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *searchString=self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSPredicate *mypredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchString];
    self.mysearchResult=[self.myList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:mypredicate];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

"CellForRowAtIndexPath" method for tableView codes:(similarly "numberOfRowsInSection" is updated)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyCustomCell codes..... 
if (tableView==self.tableView) {
        cell.cellLabel.text=[self.myList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else 
        cell.cellLabel.text=[self.mysearchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you assign tabeView's dataSource and delegate?

Comment: Do you have only one TableView? If so your if condition will always be true. and your data is always getting loaded from self.myList. Solution is provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first time before populating the tableView use `mysearchResult`instead of `myList`. At this point data in both arrays should be same.

```
self.mysearchResult = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:myList];
```

Now after using predicate you are updating your `mysearchResult` that's fine. While you cancel search again populate your `mysearchResult` from `myList` which actually contains all your original data.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    [self.mysearchResult count];
}
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyCustomCell codes..... 

//Remove your If condition from here
        cell.cellLabel.text=[self.mysearchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's showing the search result now. Currently when I click on search Bar, it hides the data before populate the table with search result which I will try to fix it in coming days. any ideas?

Comment: please verify in search bar delegates methods. May be your array is getting empty in that method and you are reloading data at that time. Secondly mark my answer as accepted ;) I solved your issue :)

Comment: even after search is canceled, the table is not reloaded back, i think i will create another tableViewcontroller similar to apple sample code. I wanted to vote but since I am new, it says I need to earn reputation first. Correct?

Comment: [Search Controller](https://github.com/Ja5onHoffman/UISearchController-Demo) hopefully it will be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks. by the way I accepted the answer, was clicking the wrong one before :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this, may be useful:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    NSString *searchString=self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSPredicate *mypredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchString];
    self.mysearchResult=[self.myList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:mypredicate];
    self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = self.mysearchResult;  
}
```

Comment: I tried Shehzad Ali solution below and it worked but thanks for your time.